# Value from LINQ dataset (GetFiles) into ListView?

Tags: c#, listview

I have the following simple page;

```
    <%@ Import namespace="System.IO" %>

<script runat="server">
    int pageSize = 10;
    int pageNum = 1;

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        var currentPage = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\mypath", "*.pdf").Skip((pageNum - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).OrderBy(c => c).ToArray();
        Listview1.DataSource = currentPage;
        Listview1.DataBind();

        base.OnInit(e);
    }

</script>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test project</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListView ID="Listview1" runat="server">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>Titel</td>
                    <td>Size</td>
                </tr>
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td><a href=''><%#Eval("Name") %></a></td>
                <td>0 kb</td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

How do i get Filename, size, path etc into my Listview. If i just had a simple for each directly on the GetFiles, i could do something like

```
FileInfo f = new FileInfo(pdfFile);
long pdfSize = f.Length;
Response.Write(Path.GetFileName(pdfFile) + " - " + pdfSize.ToString() + "<br/>");
```

But how do i achive this in my ListView?

Comment: I found that maybe this could lead me in the right direction `<%# Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Eval("Name").ToString())%>`. But i am still getting "DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'Name'."

Not sure what else i could use besides "Name"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are selecting the paths to the files not the files itself. Hence you cannot get the `FileInfo`'s properties what raises your exception *"DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'Name'"*

This should work:

```
var currentPage = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\mypath", "*.pdf").Skip((pageNum - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).OrderBy(c => c).ToArray();
        .Skip((pageNum - 1) * pageSize)
        .Take(pageSize)
        .OrderBy(c => c)
        .Select(path => new System.IO.FileInfo(path)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to create a new listviewitem collection and add your values to the collection using a loop. Then add the listviewitems back to the listview.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.items.aspx